# SSRS - Line break in Matrix cell

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, line-breaks, ssrs-2012

In a SSRS Matrix cell I want to be able to have a line break between each output given.

I have the following code in my MS SQL Server Stored Procedure which I then point my SSRS report to

```
SELECT Customer, Hostname, (QName + QHostname + Qtag + QSerial + QCategory + QType + QItem + QManu + QModel + QVersion) AS AdditionalInfo1 
FROM TableQ
```

At the moment in the AdditionalInfo1 cell when one of the options is returned they are separated by a comma

e.g.

QName, QHostname, Qtag.

Instead I would like them to be separated by a line break all within the same cell

e.g.

QName

QHostname

Qtag

I have tried putting + char(13) + between each Q... in AdditionalInfo1 but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SSRS, you want to use Chr(10), not Chr(13).  I've used this in expressions and as a Join delimiter argument and it produced the desired effect: line breaks within the textbox.

**Edit:**

Below is an expression that will include the fields with line breaks if a value is present, or omit both if the field is null.

```
=Fields!QName.Value
+ IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!QHostname.Value),"", vbCrLf + Fields!QHostname.Value)
+ IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Qtag.Value),"", vbCrLf + Fields!Qtag.Value)
+ IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!QSerial.Value),"", vbCrLf + Fields!QSerial.Value)
+ IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!QCategory.Value),"", vbCrLf + Fields!QCategory.Value)
+ IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!QType.Value),"", vbCrLf + Fields!QType.Value)
+ IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!QItem.Value),"", vbCrLf + Fields!QItem.Value)
+ IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!QManu.Value),"", vbCrLf + Fields!QManu.Value)
+ IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!QModel.Value),"", vbCrLf + Fields!QModel.Value)
+ IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!QVersion.Value),"", vbCrLf + Fields!QVersion.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway if there is no data for one of the fields that it doesn't do a carriage return? Currently my cells are quite large because of all the gaps. So basically if there is a NULL then don't carriage return.

Comment: Certainly.  I've amended the post above - concatenating that should give you your desired result.

Comment: Sorry so how would I put that into the query above?

Comment: Leave the fields separate in the query, but use the above as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating all the 'Q' columns into a single string keep them as separate fields. Then create individual [placeholders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207048.aspx#Anchor_0) in a single cell, one for each field. You can do this quite quickly by clicking into the cell (which is rich TextBox) and typing the field name (as it appears in the DataSet) enclosed by square brackets

eg:

```
[QName]
[QHostname]
[Qtag]
```